Planck Length Calculation
On this question, from long ago, the Planck length is calculated as the length at which the Reduced Compton Wavelength is equal to the Schwarzschild Radius. However, in the calculation, the scalar "2" in the formula for the Schwarzschild radius is omitted in subsequent calculations. If I follow the calculations to their conclusion, with the 2 included, I get

when the Schwarzschild Radius is equal to the Planck length, the Reduced Compton Wavelength is equal to double the Planck length.

I must be doing something wrong, but I am not sufficiently far along in my studies to know where the problem is. Can anyone help me understand where the 2 went, please?

The Planck length is an order of magnitude estimate of a scale that should be relevant for quantum gravity, based on dimensional analysis. Factors of 2 are not relevant for this kind of analysis; or, stated differently, we don't have enough confidence or precision in this estimate for it to be meaningful to worry about factors of 2.

You might pick the length as that where the Compton wavelength recedes behind the Schwarzschild horizon with increasing energy. Staying within an order of magnitude is no big deal for any "practical" (?) purposes...

A more detailed analysis has to consider the fact, that radial lenghts are not metrically invariants and have no inner radial end inside the horizon to decribe a standing wave.
The Schwarzschild radial coordinate $r$ is defined by the metric surface $4 \pi r^2 $ of a sphere, as is evident by the metric term $r^2 d\theta^2 + r^2 \sin^2\theta d\phi^2$ as in flat space. So the Planck  lenght is tied somehow to angular momentum spectrum on a metric sphere, e.g.  by   Bohr's length of a single wave $e^{i\phi}$ along the equator on the horizon.
